# Real-time Server Status and Information

Tags: php, node.js, webserver, dashboard

Last week, I found an admin panel on WrapBootstrap which contains a Dashboard page. This page was awesome because it was containing some server informations about the load and the status.

There's a list:

- Server Load (in real-time, 30ms)
- Disk space usage
- Bandwidth
- Memory usage (in real-time)
- Network usage
- Uptime (seconds included)
- System Log
- OS information
- CPU usage for each core (real-time)
- Other CPU information
- etc.

I know that a lot of this cannot be done using PHP but I'm welling to use Node.js or Python, if someone help me... I'm able to do some using PHP but not these unfortunately...

If someone knows how I can create that, it would be awesome!

Note: I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on an EC2 instance.

Comment: That's possible but requires a lot of scripting. You can use [Comet Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) to start with.

Comment: You can do all of that in php. http://rk4an.github.io/phpsysinfo/

Comment: @Dave Please write this as an anwser, I'll accept it.

Comment: @FrederickMarcoux done as requested also added in a couple of other things you may want to look at. Personally I use Munin - Graphing and Icinga - Monitoring on my cluster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do all of that in php.

http://rk4an.github.io/phpsysinfo

You may also want to look at MRTG, Nagios etc too all monitoring and server status stuff